# Adding a watermark to image with php at upload

Tags: php, image-uploading, watermark, image-upload

I am using this code for uploading, and resizing an image. (Now, i only use the cropImage function, because i only need a thumb at this part)

With this code, i get the errors below:
Warning: imagesx() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in /home/fayszakk/domain.hu/cms/uj-video.php on line 67

Warning: imagesy() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in /home/fayszakk/domain.hu/cms/uj-video.php on line 67

Warning: imagecopy() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in /home/fayszakk/domain.hu/cms/uj-video.php on line 67

```
if($_FILES['termek_file']['size'] != 0 )
{
    $ThumbSquareSize        = $hir_thumb_size;
    $BigImageMaxSize        = $hir_big_size;
    $ThumbPrefix            = "th-";
    $DestinationDirectory   = '../images/youtube/';
    $Quality                = $imgQuality;

    $stamp = imagecreatefrompng('../images/assets/play.png');
    $marge_right = 10;
    $marge_bottom = 10;
    $sx = imagesx($stamp);
    $sy = imagesy($stamp);


    if(!isset($_FILES['termek_file']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['termek_file']['tmp_name']))
    {
        $error[] = "Elképzelhető, hogy nem választott ki fényképet.";
    }
    $RandomNumber   = rand(0, 99999999);
    $ImageName      = str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($_FILES['termek_file']['name']));
    $ImageSize      = $_FILES['termek_file']['size'];
    $TempSrc        = $_FILES['termek_file']['tmp_name'];
    $ImageType      = $_FILES['termek_file']['type'];
    switch(strtolower($ImageType))
    {
        case 'image/png':
            $CreatedImage =  imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['termek_file']['tmp_name']);
            break;
        case 'image/gif':
            $CreatedImage =  imagecreatefromgif($_FILES['termek_file']['tmp_name']);
            break;
        case 'image/jpeg':
        case 'image/pjpeg':
            $CreatedImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['termek_file']['tmp_name']);
            break;
        default:
        $error[] = "Nem támogatott fájlformátum.";
    }
    list($CurWidth,$CurHeight)=getimagesize($TempSrc);
    $ImageExt = substr($ImageName, strrpos($ImageName, '.'));
    $ImageExt = str_replace('.','',$ImageExt);
    $ImageName      = preg_replace("/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/", "", $ImageName);
    $NewImageName = $ImageName.'-'.$RandomNumber.'.'.$ImageExt;
    $thumb_DestRandImageName    = $DestinationDirectory.$ThumbPrefix.$NewImageName;
    $DestRandImageName          = $DestinationDirectory.$NewImageName;
    /*if(!resizeImage($CurWidth,$CurHeight,$BigImageMaxSize,$DestRandImageName,$CreatedImage,$Quality,$ImageType))
    {
        $error[] = "A fénykép átméretezése nem sikerült.";

    }*/
    imagecopy($thumb_DestRandImageName, $stamp, imagesx($thumb_DestRandImageName) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($thumb_DestRandImageName) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));
    if(!cropImage($CurWidth,$CurHeight,$ThumbSquareSize,$thumb_DestRandImageName,$CreatedImage,$Quality,$ImageType))
    {
        $error[] = "Nem sikerült a bélyegkép készítése.";
    }
}
else
{
    $error[] = "Nem választott ki fényképet.";
}
```

Can someone help me, that how can i add that watermark to the uploaded images?

Comment: Use `imagecopy`: http://php.net/manual/en/image.examples-watermark.php

Comment: the above code would throw errors if something other than an image were uploaded ~ need to process the `type` or use `$error` for logic tests

Comment: I updated my first post and the code. I checked the site you added, but i get errors.